# how to duplicate and store a final copy of an array that would not change value enven after passing it using methods

Tags: arrays, sorting, user-defined-functions, final

When I run this program after entering values for elements and choose bubble sorting everything works fine but after selecting other kind of sorting such as selection the array elements that it was supposed to
arranged was already arranged, and I think that's because the array
elements that it reads is the arranged one instead of the order of
array elements that the user has entered in the beginning of the
program.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
        public class sample{
                static int[] array_elements;
                static int limit;
                static int x; 
                static int ctr;
                static int swap;
                static int i; 
                static int j;
                static int p;
                //static final int[] elements= array_elements;
                public static void user(){
                    //final int[] elements= array_elements;
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("[Minimum 5 and Maximum 15]");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Please enter size of the Array: ");
                    limit = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println();
                    if(limit<5 || limit>15){
                        System.out.println("The Array Size Is Out Of Range. Try Again!!!");
                        System.out.print('\u000c');
                        user();
                    } 
                    else {
                        array_elements = new int [limit];
                        System.out.println("Please Enter " + limit + " Elements to store: ");
                        System.out.println();
                        for(ctr = 0; ctr <= limit -1; ctr++){
                            System.out.print("Enter element "+(ctr+1)+" :\t");
                            array_elements[ctr] = in.nextInt();
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        Back();
                    }
                    //return String.valueOf(elements);
                }
                
                
                public static void Back(){
                    System.out.print("Press any key to continue.");
                    try{
                        System.in.read();
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {    
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.print('\u000c');
                    menu();
                }
                
                public static void menu(){
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("\n\t\t\tSorting Algorithms");
                    System.out.println("\t\tMenu");
                    System.out.println("\t[ 1 ] Bubble Sort");
                    System.out.println("\t[ 2 ] Selection Sort");
                    System.out.println("\t[ 3 ] Insertion Sort");
                    System.out.println("\t[ 4 ] Exit");
                    
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Enter Choice: ");
                    int choices = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println();
                    
                    switch(choices){
                        case 1:
                           BubbleSort();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            selectionSort();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            
                            break;
                        case 4:
                           Exit();
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.print("ERROR");
                            System.out.println("\u000c");
                            menu();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                
                    public static void BubbleSort() {
                    System.out.print("Given Array Alements: ");
                        for(ctr = 0; ctr <= limit - 1; ctr++){
                            x++;
                            System.out.printf("%5d" , array_elements[ctr]);
                        }
                    //user(elements);
                    System.out.println();
                    for (i = 0; i < ( limit - 1 ); i++) {
                        
                          for (j = 0; j < limit - i - 1; j++) {
                            if (array_elements[j] > array_elements[j+1]) 
                            {
                              swap       = array_elements[j];
                              array_elements[j]   = array_elements[j+1];
                              array_elements[j+1] = swap;
                            }
                          }
                      System.out.println();
                      System.out.print((i+1)+".\t");
                     
                         for (int i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++){
                                int j = array_elements[i];
                                System.out.print(j + " ");
                         }
                      System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Sorted list of numbers: ");
                 
                        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
                          System.out.printf("%5d" , array_elements[i]);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    Back();
                }
                
                    public static void selectionSort(){
                    System.out.print("Given Array Alements: ");
                            for(ctr = 0; ctr <= limit - 1; ctr++){
                                x++;
                                System.out.printf("%5d" , array_elements[ctr]);
                            }
                    System.out.println();
                        for (i = 0; i < ( limit - 1 ); i++) { 
                            
                                 for (int i = 0; i < array_elements.length - 1; i++){  
                                    int index = i;  
                                        for (int j = i + 1; j < array_elements.length; j++){  
                                            if (array_elements[j] <array_elements[index]){  
                                                index = j;//searching for lowest index  
                                            }  
                                        }  
                                    int smallerNumber = array_elements[index];   
                                    array_elements[index] = array_elements[i];  
                                    array_elements[i] = smallerNumber;  
                                }  
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.print((i+1)+".\t");
                             
                                 for (int i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++){
                                        int j = array_elements[i];
                                        System.out.print(j + " ");
                                 }
                              System.out.println();
                        }  
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Sorted list of numbers: ");
                 
                        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
                            System.out.printf("%5d" , array_elements[i]);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    Back();
                }
                
                
                public static void Exit(){
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
                    System.out.println("Would you like to Continue with the process? ");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Y/y or N/n: " );
                    char ans = sc.next().charAt(0);
                    
                    switch(ans){
                        case 'y':
                        case 'Y':
                            System.out.print("Press any key to continue.");
                            System.out.print('\u000c');
                            main(null);
                            break;
                        case 'n':
                        case 'N':
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("PROGRAM TERMINATED");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("INVALID CHOICE TRY AGAIN! CHOOSE Y/n OR N/n ONLY!");
                            System.out.println();
                            Exit();
                    }
                }
                
                public static void main (String[] args){
                    user();
                }
        }
```

I thought of using final keyword but until now it is still not
working.

I hope you guys can help me with this one, I apologize for my
wrong grammar in advance.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add output console log

Comment: @user17069403 - You have only one array `array_elements`. How can you wonder that the array is sorted after you sorted it?